# Permissions API for the web

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions there is a Browser Support table indicate that some browser don't support Permissions API

Also as far as I understand , when a user reject permission request there is no way to request permission again

I need to create two functions `checkPermission` and `grantPermission` , these function return `resolved` promise when we have permission and `rejected` promise when not

1. For the browser that don't support Permissions API , What must I do? If I return `rejected` promise may be NO PERMISSION IS REQUIRED FOR THAT BROWSER !! If I return `resolved` may be my app works wrong!
2. Is there any library wrapped permission api?

Answer (score 1):

In order to check if the browser supports permissions:

```
if(!navigator.permissions){
    // Browser does not support permissions
}
```

Also, if you are working with promises, reject and resolve methods have an optional parameter to pass some data:

```js
function testPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!navigator.permissions) {
      reject('Unsupported Browser');
    } else {
      resolve('Supported Browser')
    }
  });
}


testPromise().then((resolved, rejected) => {
  if (rejected) {
    console.log(rejected);
    return;
  }
  console.log(resolved);
})
```